# What does 'invalid instance method invocant: no hash ref supplied' mean in Class::XSAccessor?

Tags: perl, runtime-error

I got this error on one of my object calls, I don't get what it even means:

`Class::XSAccessor: invalid instance method invocant: no hash ref supplied`

Answer (score 1):

**Check whether you are making a class method call where Class::XSAccessor is expecting an instance method call.**

In other words, the error message means what it says--it expects a blessed hash ref, and you didn't give it one.

In my case, the problem was that I was doing a `$package_name->method` call; what was needed was for me to make the same call against an *instance* of the class.  So, for my situation, it was sufficient to simply do `$package_name->new()->method`.